# Write access to NTFS drives

Tags: filesystems, fstab, manjaro, administration, read-write

Never had this problem before. The drives will not give me write access
Drives are ntfs.
Fstab was set on default, now tried rw option and nothing.
Using Manjaro.

How can I get write access to drives?

Those are the permissions at the mount point:

```
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 mar 30 03:23 Hitachi
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root 8192 mar 28 13:05 Tor
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root 4096 mar 28 13:05 WD
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root 4096 abr 10 01:10 Win10
```

fstab entries:

```
UUID=821840AA18409F53 /home/poldini/Desktop/Win10 ntfs auto,rw,noatime 
0 2 
UUID=E600C8DD00C8B5B9 /home/poldini/Desktop/WD ntfs 
auto,rw,noatime 0 2 
UUID=0356C5240C356E1A /home/poldini/Desktop/Torr 
ntfs auto,rw,noatime 0 2 
UUID=76222aac-470c-4d9d-97e4-f2cf0afeef4d 
/home/poldini/Desktop/Hitachi ext4 auto,rw,noatime 0 2
```

mount output:

```
/dev/sdb2 on /home/poldini/Desktop/Win10 type fuseblk 
(ro,nosuid,nodev,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)

/dev/sdc2 on /home/poldini/Desktop/WD type fuseblk 
(ro,nosuid,nodev,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096) [WD]

/dev/sde1 on /home/poldini/Desktop/Hitachi type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)

/dev/sda1 on /home/poldini/Desktop/Torr type fuseblk
(ro,nosuid,nodev,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 12 root    root    4096 mar 30 03:23 Hitachi
drwxrwxrwx  1 root    root    8192 mar 28 13:05 Tor
drwxrwxrwx  1 root    root    4096 mar 28 13:05 WD
drwxrwxrwx  1 root    root    4096 abr 10 01:10 Win10

Those are the permissions at the mount point.

Comment: Maybe the filesystems have been remounted R/O after a disk error?  Are the SMART data OK?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all relevant information. Comments aren't meant for that.

Comment: add the output of `mount` - the output should show whether they're mounted rw or ro. If they're read-only, a reboot would potentially bring the disk(s) back up as read-write based on your fstab.
side note; mounting drives with 777 permissions is generally a bad idea..

Comment: So yes the ext4 drive is writable.
How do I set permissions? 'user_id=?' ?

Answer (score 8):

For me this was a problem and as correctly identified by @Leopoldini this is a problem with Windows Disk Write Caching. I have tested this with Windows 10 and Fedora and it worked for me.

Steps I followed were as below,

```
Win 10, first go to,

Device Manager  ->  Disk Drives

Then, select the disk you want to disable caching - right click -> Properties -> Policies -> Write-Caching policy

Uncheck "Enable write caching on the device"
```

That's it.. Reboot to Linux ( for me it is Fedora 28 ). Now you will see the disk got mounted with "rw" permission.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my problem

Answer (score 4):

The Linux NTFS kernel module (CONFIG_NTFS_FS) provides read-only access to NTFS volumes; It does not support read-write access. To get read-write access you need either:

1. Read-write support enabled (CONFIG_NTFS_RW, not recommended)
2. Use the FUSE-based NTFS-3G module (recommended)

Why is the built-in module not recommended?

> [CONFIG_NTFS_RW] enables the partial, but safe, write support in the NTFS driver.
>   The only supported operation is overwriting existing files, without
>   changing the file length. No file or directory creation, deletion or
>   renaming is possible. Note only non-resident files can be written to
>   so you may find that some very small files (<500 bytes or so) cannot
>   be written to. - https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NTFS_RW.html

Assuming you have [NTFS-3G](https://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/) installed, to use the module replace `ntfs` with `ntfs-3g` in your `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=821840AA18409F53 /home/poldini/Desktop/Win10 ntfs-3g auto,rw,noatime 
0 2 
UUID=E600C8DD00C8B5B9 /home/poldini/Desktop/WD ntfs-3g 
auto,rw,noatime 0 2 
UUID=0356C5240C356E1A /home/poldini/Desktop/Torr 
ntfs-3g auto,rw,noatime 0 2 
UUID=76222aac-470c-4d9d-97e4-f2cf0afeef4d 
/home/poldini/Desktop/Hitachi ext4 auto,rw,noatime 0 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I had suspected but wanted to see if there was a work around.

Windows cache features need to be turned of for the disks. Once I did that via windows all privileges were granted.